# IE11 IDBIndex.openCursor() for a compound index returns no results

Tags: internet-explorer, indexeddb

I am having a problem with IE11 with code that works in Google Chrome.

Consider the following query on an object store with a compound key typekey which has two fields: type,docID

```
store.createIndex("typekey", [ "type", "docID" ], { unique: false });
```

...

```
idb.transaction("inbox")
    .objectStore("inbox")
    .index("typekey")
    .openCursor()
    .onsuccess = function(e) { 
      debugger;
      // e.target.result is null, even though there are records in the objectStore 
    };
```

Consider a query on the same table using the primary key.

```
idb.transaction("inbox")
    .objectStore("inbox")
    .openCursor()
    .onsuccess = function(e) { 
      debugger;
      // e.target.result is an IDBCursorWithValue as expected
    };
```

Why is Internet Explorer not returning any results in the first instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Multi-entry indexes and compound indexes are not the same thing. However, IE doesn't support either feature." –  dumbmatter Nov 1 at 3:29

(from a comment below)

Answer (score 2):

Polyfill for IE:

https://github.com/dfahlander/idb-iegap

...makes IE behave as Chrome and Firefox with compound and multiEntry indexes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the reference page for [createIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772586(v=vs.85).aspx), IE doesn't support multi-entry indexes.

There's a [related thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/55eb469b-6c1b-40bc-97a6-a37174d87af8/indexeddb-multientry?forum=winappswithhtml5) on the Windows Dev forums that talks about a possible direction for workarounds.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Multi-entry indexes and compound indexes are not the same thing. However, IE doesn't support either feature.

Comment: I am not using multiEntry, also specifying an array (sequence of strings) and multiEntry: true is illegal according to the spec.  

"If keyPath is a sequence<DOMString> and the multiEntry property in the optionalParameters is true, the implementation must throw a DOMException of type InvalidAccessError."

Comment: dumbmatter if you add your comment as an answer, I can mark this question as answered